# How to animate multiple objects in qml

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, qml

and im trying to animate several objects at once, using sequential animation. For my purposes I need to access it from outside of the sequential animation (and number animation) decleration's. This works fine, but only animates one object at a time when set. If i define a number animation per object, this will work -- but i do not want to do this, because later I want to assign the animations within a loop which will vary in size. So im deliberately calling the same number animation object. Is there a way to animate a bunch of objects without defining each number animation for it? Here's some code:

```
   Component.onCompleted: {

   seq.access.target = rec1
   seq.access.property = "y"
   seq.access.to = 50
   seq.start()


   seq.access.target = rec2
   seq.access.property = "y"
   seq.access.to = 50
   seq.start()

}

Rectangle{
    id: rec1
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "red"
}
Rectangle{
    id: rec2
    x: 100
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "blue"
}

SequentialAnimation{
    id: seq
    property alias access: num
    NumberAnimation{id: num}
}
```

**UPDATE** Hi guy's thanks for your response's. The above problem has been solved by GrecKo's solution, but im still not there yet... i need to be able to make each target or targets setting in a loop. I thought that by getting the above code working, it should/would work if the same targets where in an array:

```
...
property int i
Component.onCompleted: {

    var array = [rec1, rec2]

    for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){

        seq.access.targets = [array[i]]
        seq.access.property = "y"
        seq.access.to = 50
        seq.start()

    }


}

Rectangle{
    id: rec1
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "red"
}

Rectangle{
    id: rec2
    x: 100
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "blue"
}
SequentialAnimation{
    id: seq
    property alias access: num
    NumberAnimation{id: num}

}
```

But it does not work. This is what i need to do. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to apply the same animation on multiple object, you can use the [`targets` property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-propertyanimation.html#targets-prop) to specify multiple targets for your animation.

In your example, you would use it like this :

```
Component.onCompleted: {
    seq.access.targets = [rec1, rec2]
    seq.access.property = "y"
    seq.access.to = 50
    seq.start()
}
```

Comment: '@GrecKo' Thanks, thats great, but what i really need it to do is work in a loop call. Something like     'Component.onCompleted: { var array = [rec1, rec2] for(i = 0; i < 2; i++){ seq.access.targets = [array[i]] seq.access.property = "y" seq.access.to = 50 seq.start() } }'

Comment: Why do you want that ?
Do you want to start them with a delay ?

Comment: Then why do you need a loop ? My code has the same behaviour as your loop if your loop did what you want.

Comment: I need a loop because the targets are coming from an array. Therefore I want to set every target on iteration over the array

Comment: the targets property takes an array of Items, no need to loop, you can do `seq.access.targets = yourItemArray`

Comment: Oh I see what u mean. I didn't know that 'targets' takes an array of items... no need for other loop. Thanks for your help this will do.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this code. Maybe this is what you are looking for. Copy this to your *main.qml*

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 1066
    height: 600

    property double time: 0

    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 20
        y: 50 + time * 250
        color: "red"
    }
    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 220
        y: 150
        rotation: time * 360
        color: "blue"
    }
    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 420
        y: 50 + Math.pow(time, 1/3) * 250
        color: "green"
    }
    Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 100
        x: 620
        y: 150
        scale: 1 + Math.pow(time, 3)
        color: "lightblue"
    }



    NumberAnimation on time {
        running: true
        loops: Animation.Infinite
        from: 0
        to: 1
        duration: 1000
    }
}
```

---

Also what may work in the example you provided is:

```
Component.onCompleted: {

   seq.access.target = rec1
   seq.access.property = "y"
   seq.access.to = 50
   seq.start()

}

Rectangle{
    id: rec1
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "red"
}
Rectangle{
    id: rec2
    x: 100
    y: rec1.y
    width: 50
    height: 50
    color: "blue"
}

SequentialAnimation{
    id: seq
    property alias access: num
    NumberAnimation{id: num}
}
```